# How to make some behaviour for the following situations?

Tags: netlogo

I have people moving forward and I need the simple code to let these people when they intersect with each other ( if the number of people in the patch exceed certain number ---> lead to danger?

the second behavior: people need to walk then stop for some time to do some task then complete their walking.. how can I code this ? is there any idea for that?

the message from the below code tell that : Nothing named >=2 has been defined?

```
to go
  ask pilgrims
    [fd 1]
    if any? other turtles-here >=2 [ set in-danger? true]
```

Comment: You need to change `>=2` to `>= 2` (insert a space before the 2). Digits are legal characters in NetLogo identifiers (as long as the digit isn't the first character), so NetLogo is seeing `>=2` is a single thing rather than two.

Comment: Thanks Seth for your help